# How to use the attach gem in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

My environment:

- Ruby 2.4.1
- Rails 5.1.4

I am trying to use the attach gem, written by the person who also wrote this article https://atech.blog/atech/file-attachments-in-rails-tutorial.

When I run the bundle install it installs attach gem, version 1.0.2

Then when I try to run the rake command I get an error saying it does not know how to build the task.

```
rake attach:install:migrations --trace

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'attach:install:migrations' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:59:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:159:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas on what the error is? I am wondering if I am missing a required gem to make it work. The link to the attach documentation is https://github.com/adamcooke/attach

Comment: After adding gem, you should install bundle and restart app.

Comment: This error occured after running bundle install and restarting the rails server.

Comment: How did you run the migration? Did you try running it with `bundle exec` like this: `bundle exec rake attach:install:migrations`?

Comment: Just tried with bundle exec, and it still give me the same error as when I ran 'rake attach:install:migrations'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no rake tasks defined in this repo.

After you run `bundle install`, you can get a list of rake tasks by running `rake -P` (`rake -T` shows tasks with descriptions). You'll see that `attach:install:migrations` is not there.

Why not try using `paperclip`?